# How can I stop "property does not exist on type JQuery" syntax errors when using Typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am only using one line of jQuery in my application:

```
$("div.printArea").printArea();
```

But this is giving me a Typescript error:

> The property 'printArea' does not exist on type JQuery?

Can someone tell me how I can stop this error appearing?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You could cast it to `<any>` or extend the jquery typing to add your own method.

```
 (<any>$("div.printArea")).printArea();
```

Or, add your own custom methods (Assuming this is added by yourself as a part of custom plugin)

```
declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        printArea(): void;
    }
}
```

Comment: giving me: `Error:(44, 23) TS2339: Property 'printArea' does not exist on type 'ElementFinder'.`

Comment: If you try the `interface JQuery` way in an external module and define a function parameter as a JQuery type and attempt to call it from another file, TypeScript will complain that there's two types named JQuery that are unrelated.

Comment: Declaring the interface seems to work great. Also its much cleaner than casting to <any> everywhere

Comment: This wasn't working for me, but eventually I stumbled across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960386/how-to-extend-the-window-typescript-interface, and realised I needed `declare global { ... }` around the interface declaration.

Answer (score 59):

I think this is the most readable solution:

```
($("div.printArea") as any).printArea();
```

Answer (score 15):

You can  cast it to

```
(<any>$('.selector') ).function();
```

Ex: date picker initialize using jquery

```
(<any>$('.datepicker') ).datepicker();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the ignore syntax instead of using  (or better the 'as any') notation:

```
// @ts-ignore
$("div.printArea").printArea();
```

Answer (score 3):

For your example, you'd add this:

```
interface JQuery{
    printArea():void;
}
```

Edit: oops, basarat is correct below. I'm not sure why I thought it was compiling but I've updated this answer.

Comment: Nope. He is wrapping an object with $. It's not static $ anymore

Comment: Hmm, you sure? I tested that in a project and it worked.

Comment: yup. Your case `$.inviewport(el)` Ops case `$('selector').printArea`

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to quibble, but my code works for me. The question seems to be about getting the code to compile, so if my code compiles, what's the issue with it? Note, my second example using printArea() works as well.

Comment: `$('selector').printArea` compiles? I don't think so. `$.printArea` will compile though. You have been very polite so no offence taken or intended :)

Comment: Yes, it compiles for me. No offense taken :-)

Comment: Oh, boy. I thought it was compiling but I guess it wasn't. I blame the IDE.

Comment: You need to wrap it inside a `declare global { }`; otherwise, it won't probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Since printArea is a jQuery plugin it is not included in jquery.d.ts.

You need to create a jquery.printArea.ts definition file.

If you create a complete definition file for the plugin you may want to submit it to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

Comment: And make sure that your tsconfig.json is setup right too. If it has a "types" setting then only the types listed will be recognized. If not, then it will recognize everything in node_modules/@types

Comment: If I define something earlier in a file, and then reference it later in a file, IntelliSense recognizes it and assists me. When I put ``/// <reference path="jquery.extension.js" />`` at the top of the file, isn't IntelliSense supposed to read that file and infer that code just as if I'd written it in my file? Instead, it's still flagging errors on my valid code.

Comment: Hmm. I guess what's happening is that `jquery.extension.js` is not declaring new types to overwrite existing types (something IntelliSense would read), but it's programmatically extending the types, and IntelliSense isn't smart enough to determine the end result of that code. Ugh. I really don't want to write a whole type file for this massive library.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it like this:

```
let elem: any;
elem = $("div.printArea");
elem.printArea();
```