# How to remove TypeScript warning: property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

In a TypeScript file, I have defined a 3D array:

```
var myArr = ['one', [[19, 1], [13, 1], [86, 1], [12, 2]],
             'two',    [[83, 1], [72, 1], [16, 2]],
             'three',  [[4, 1]]];

function testArray(){
    console.log(myArr[1].length);
}
```

I get a warning under the length property:

> Property 'length' does not exist on type '{}'

Is there something I can do to remove this warning?

Comment: Works fine, perhaps your error is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/yxrufk86/

Comment: I think that it's because you are mixing strings and arrays, and although both have a `length` property, there is no common interface for that, so the type of the array is an array of objects.

Comment: @ Omri: Yes the code does work ok. It is not an error. It is just a warning, but it hinders development because it is a "false" warning and I can't get rid of it...

Comment: @ Guffa: If I replace the strings with numbers I get the same warning message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1: upgrade to bleeding-edge compiler and get union types

Option 2: Add a type annotation to the variable declaration:

```
var myArr: any[] = ['one', [[19, 1], [13, 1], [86, 1], [12, 2]],
             'two',    [[83, 1], [72, 1], [16, 2]],
             'three',  [[4, 1]]];

function testArray(){
    console.log(myArr[1].length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 does work. What do you mean by option 1? I am using TypeScript 1.3.0

Comment: The next release, 1.4, will have union types. You can grab tsc.js from the GitHub repo to try it out.

Answer (score 30):

I read a similar post here:
[How can I stop "property does not exist on type JQuery" syntax errors when using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984014/how-can-i-stop-property-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery-syntax-errors-when-using)

Which explains that I can cast to <any>.

This worked for me:

```
function testArray(){
    console.log((<any>myArr[1]).length);
}
```

Comment: in jsx:

{(data as any).length && ... }

Comment: @LeonardoNobreGhiggino worked at typescript too in angular, thanks

Answer (score 8):

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
> for...in loop. (The only difference is that a for...in loop enumerates
> properties in the prototype chain as well.)

```
Object.values(myArr).length
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 2):

i faced this error before,you have to cast the type to any and when you
use generics you have to extends.

check the example blow:

```
const result = <T extends any>(arr:T[]):T => {
  return arr[arr.length - 1] 
}

result([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who **already have a interface/type/class configured and would like it to have a length** or something else i have a suggestion that i use. Inside the class, interface, type put the code below. It will set unknown only on undefined attributes. It is not necessary to put it at the end, I also suggest that you create a separate interface and extend it to your objects if you prefer

```
export interface x {
...
[props: string]: unknown 
...
}
```

This will make it possible for you to use any attribute name in your object, as bad as it sounds, it actually isn't. That's because for each unknown attribute you will be forced([T.S 4.4+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html)) to do a forced conversion to some other type when you use, eg

```
(object.length as number).
```

When analyzing the possible type of the attribute you will be more careful and will not try to access something that does not exist. **Don't worry about your object auto-completion, it will keep working normally**