# How to extend the 'Window' typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5, fetch-api

In my example, I'm trying to extend the TS Window interface to include a polyfill for `fetch`. Why doesn't matter. The question is "***how do I tell TS that `window.fetch` is a valid function?***"

> I'm doing this in VS Code, v.0.3.0 which is running TS v.1.5 (IIRC).

Declaring the interface inside my TS class file where I want to use it doesn't work:

```
///<reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

interface Window {
  fetch:(url: string, options?: {}) => Promise<any>
}
...
window.fetch('/blah').then(...); // TS objects that window doesn't have fetch
```

But it's OK if I declare this same interface in a separate ".d.ts" file and reference it in my TS class file.

Here is "typings/window.extend.d.ts"

```
///<reference path="es6-promise/es6-promise"/>
interface Window {
  fetch:(url: string, options?: {}) => Promise<any>
}
```

Now I can use it in my TS class file:

```
///<reference path="typings/window.extend.d.ts"/>
...
window.fetch('/blah').then(...); // OK
```

Alternatively, I can write an extending interface *with another name* in my TS class file and then use it in a cast:

```
interface WindowX extends Window {
  fetch:(url: string, options?: {}) => Promise<any>
}
...
(<WindowX> window).fetch('/blah').then(...); // OK
```

**Why does extending the interface work in a "d.ts" but not *in situ*?**

**Do I really have to go through these gyrations?**

Comment: A clarifying question .... What is the best way to accomplish extending an interface? I see pros and cons to both of these

Answer (score 50):

You need the `declare global`

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    fetch:(url: string, options?: {}) => Promise<any>
  }
}
```

This works then:

```
window.fetch('/blah').then(...);
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? For me, the things I declare globally in one module are not visible in other modules. Any clue?

Comment: The answer below helps clarify why this works. See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

Answer (score 22):

When you have a top-level `import` or `export` in your file (which you must somewhere to be having this problem), your file is an *external module*.

In an external module, declaring an interface always creates a new type rather than augmenting an existing global interface. This mimics the general behavior of module loaders -- that things declared in this file don't merge or interfere with things in the global scope.

The reason for this gyration is that otherwise there wouldn't be a way to, in an external module, define new variables or types with the same name as those in the global scope.

Comment: Can you provide a link to some documentation on this issue? Perhaps the [Declaration Merging](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Declaration-Merging) wiki entry needs to be extended?

Comment: I **do** have top-level `import` statements. What you say makes sense now that I understand. But I still don't know the pros/cons of the two approaches that worked or if there is a better 3rd way. I'm sure that extending `window` will be a common scenario that should be clearly documented. [Declaration Merging](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Declaration-Merging) surely needs elaboration ... especially since the `interface Document` example *would not work in my use case*!

Comment: We love typings when they are accurate. We loathe them when they are not. Having a clean path to extend them is important. Id like to know other options here too

Comment: The clean way is to put them in another file. There's not really another way to indicate that you want to declare something in the global namespace.

Comment: For anyone using Angular 2 the interface definition goes in **src\typings.d.ts** and the actual assignment go anywhere else but most likely in **src\app\shared\index.ts**

Comment: It is possible to extend the `window` object from within an external module. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40204572/274837