# How to extend JQuery functions in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, interface, es6-modules

I'm rewriting some JS code on TypeScript and encounter with problems with module import. For example, I want to write my `toggleVisiblity` function. Here is code:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

import * as $ from "jquery";

interface JQuery {
    toggleVisibility(): JQuery;
}

$.fn.extend({
    toggleVisibility: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            const $this = $(this);
            const visibility = $this.css('visibility') === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
            $this.css('visibility', visibility);
        });
    }
});

const jQuery = $('foo');
const value = jQuery.val();
jQuery.toggleVisibility();
```

But the problem is that for unknown reason `toggleVisibility` is not added to `JQuery` interface thus I get an error `Property 'toggleVisibility' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.`, although it sees other methods (`val`, `each` and so on).

Why is it not working?

[image]

Comment: It seems your interface `JQuery` is not merged with the original one. Maybe it should be imported. How have you imported the definitions for jQuery ? With the new _@types_ system?

Comment: @Paleo with `tsd install jQuery --save` afair

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try putting the

```
interface JQuery {
    toggleVisibility(): JQuery;
}
```

Inside a seperate file without import/export statements.
This works for me. Though it wold be interesting to know why.

**EDIT**: There is an excellent explanation for this behaviour in this answer to post:
[How to extend the 'Window' typescript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960386/how-to-extend-the-window-typescript-interface#answer-30961346)

Comment: I'm going to create an issue in TS github, maybe it will be fixed. Thank you for an answer.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Please give the link to the issue, I'm interested too.

Comment: For those who are struggling to know where to put this file (like myself); this [link](https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/) explains very well.

Comment: Oh thank goodness I found this post.  I was starting to grow gray hairs over documenting this API.

Answer (score 11):

I got the solution, this worked for me:

Use the JQueryStatic interface for static jQuery access like $.jGrowl(...) or jQuery.jGrowl(...) or in your case, jQuery.toggleVisibility():

```
interface JQueryStatic {

    ajaxSettings: any;

    jGrowl(object?, f?): JQuery;

}
```

And for your own custom made functions you use using jQuery.fn.extend, use the JQuery interface:

```
interface JQuery {

    fileinput(object?): void;//custom jquery plugin, had no typings

    enable(): JQuery;

    disable(): JQuery;

    check(): JQuery;

    select_custom(): JQuery;

}
```

Optional, here are my extended JQuery functions:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    disable: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            this.disabled = true;
        });
    },
    enable: function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            this.disabled = false;
        });
    },
    check: function (checked) {
        if (checked) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
        }
        return this.prop('checked', checked);
    },
    select_custom: function (value) {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('value') == value) {
                $(this).click();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach seems to clobber the `JQuery` declarations for regular functions, like `.click()` and `.parent()`.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with my bootstrapDP function extending JQuery in the same way.

**Solution:**

```
    declare global {
        interface JQuery {
            bootstrapDP: any;  // replace 'any' with the actual type if known
        }
    }
```

**Explanation**:

This code declares a global augmentation of the JQuery interface, adding  my bootstrapDP method to it. After adding this code, TypeScript should recognize bootstrapDP as a method on jQuery objects.

Here is some documentation about global auhmentation: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)