# Typescript does not pick up on Type alias - Svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte

so I am trying to implement google analytics in my svelte-kit app. For that I need to insert a little script in the +layout.svelte file. As friends recommended me to switch from JS to TS I try to do it in TS, but I am still very noob.
[image]

So I declared this interface with the same name as the "window" object, which according to the ts-handbook is called an alias and should be picked up automatically, but it is not as you can see - my linter is screaming at me that "Property 'dataLayer' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)"
[image]

I really appreciate your help in this matter in order to fix this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can only extend types you already imported, and `window` is an ambient type, so you cannot change or import it. You can re-declare `window` like this:

###### [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIEEDqoAmB7Ad2QG8AoZZHOMOAGTgE9oAuZAJQgTyhwB4BnMFFABzADTI4IBgD4A2gF0A3KQC+pADYQwyIgF5duQpP7IAFBmwh8RAGTIwDAA4Q8MQ9cIBKUsHdmCADoqGnomKGRbeyD8BABXAFsIcEjowJA8EABRAA9gQWSwLxJVIA)

```
interface GAWindow {
  dataLayer: Record<string, any>[];
}
let w = window as (GAWindow & typeof window)
if (w.dataLayer) {}
```

(Note: This is the case because extending `window` is not really type-safe, so TS has no native support for it because it is inherently unsafe, so you have to explicitly use another variable. You can also [declare `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960386/how-to-extend-the-window-typescript-interface), but then the change is global, which you might want to avoid.)

Comment: So is the solution you proposed best practice - or what would be the best practice to do in this case? Because according to the duplicate Answers answerer I only have this problem because of a top-level import (in this case I import 2 svelte components) which I can hardly avoid. So how would I go about it in the "proper" way?