# Error when using "npm start"

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-start

I'm getting errors with npm start. I wouldn't mind, but it causes me to not be able to run the server and view my local website. It's just because I use [bootstrap-multiselect plugin](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) which has no d.ts (typing) file created for it so in my ts file it has an error where I call $("#category-select").multiselect({}) saying:

> property 'multiselect' does not exist on type jquery.

So my terminal says this when I use npm start:

> Multiselect.component.ts(16,31): error TS2339: Property 'multiselect'
>   does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

And then it won't start the local server. It is a complete blocker to my work. The bootstrap-multiselect plugin is very good and I do need to have it.

How can I either get it to ignore this error and continue to start the local server, or stop the error from happening?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "the-vegan-repository",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lite-server-test": "lite-server --config=liteserver-test-config.json",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite-server-test\" ",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"sass --watch app\" \"sass --watch index.scss\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "jquery": "v3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "codelyzer": "0.0.26",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24984067/3935156)

I just casted to any:

```
(<any>$("#category-select")).multiselect();
```

I will leave this question open for now as there may be more answers.