# Angular4 ERROR fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

I am beginner in Angular and I want to import the method fullCalendar from Jquery, but it gives me an exception saying:

> Angular4 ERROR
>   TypeError:**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery**(...).fullCalendar is
>   not a function

This is my code:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';
import 'style-loader!./baFullCalendar.scss';
@Component({
  selector: 'ba-full-calendar',
  templateUrl: './baFullCalendar.html',
})
export class BaFullCalendar {
  @Input() baFullCalendarConfiguration:Object;
  @Input() baFullCalendarClass:string;
  @Output() onCalendarReady = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild('baFullCalendar') public _selector:ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let calendar = jQuery(this._selector.nativeElement).fullCalendar(this.baFullCalendarConfiguration);
    this.onCalendarReady.emit(calendar);
  }
}
```

And this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ngx-admin",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:hmr": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start:aot": "ng serve --aot",
    "build": "rimraf dist && ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod",
    "build:prod:aot": "npm run build:prod -- --aot",
    "build:ci": "npm-run-all -p -r build:prod build:prod:aot",
    "test": "ng test -sr",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- -cc",
    "lint": "ng lint --type-check",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.2",
    "@asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet": "2.1.4",
    "@nebular/auth": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@nebular/theme": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "5.2.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.0.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.3.0",
    "angular2-color-picker": "^1.3.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "4.0.0",
    "angular2-tree-component": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "4.8.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.5",
    "leaflet": "1.0.3",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.6",
    "nebular-icons": "1.0.6",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.6",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-tree": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "ng2-wizard": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.3",
    "ngx-echarts": "1.2.2",
    "ngx-loading": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.4.1-beta.0",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.6.1",
    "ngx-uploader": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-wizard": "0.0.46",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tree-flatten": "^1.0.0",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.0.60",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.74",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "0.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.4.2",
    "tslint-language-service": "0.9.6",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
}
```

I tried to cast jQuery with "any" like many post said here in stackoverflow:[How can I stop "property does not exist on type JQuery" syntax errors when using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984014/how-can-i-stop-property-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery-syntax-errors-when-using) and I even declared it like global variable, but nothing gives more affect.

Comment: Have you imported jquery as `import * as $ from 'jquery'` ?

Comment: Try using ng-fullcalendar npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-fullcalendar. StackBlitz Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo