# JQuery plugins not working in angular 7 application

Tags: jquery, angular

I have this snippet of code in my angular.json :

```
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
          "./node_modules/alertify.js/dist/js/alertify.js",
          "./src/assets/jquery/zoomple/zoomple.js"
        ]
```

I have this code in my BaseComponent :

```
declare var $;
window["$"] = $;
window["jQuery"] = $;
```

Jquery works but zoomple (or others included plugins) doesn't work.

```
ngOnInit() {           
  this.http.get(
    this.configurationService.configuration['api_url']+"/generator/component/entitiesList").subscribe(
    data => {
      this.entities = data;
    }
  );
  $(document).ready(function() {
    (<any> $('.loupe')).okzoom({
      width: 200,
      height: 150
    });
  });
}
```

** UPDATED **

**Now the code compile but Plugin are not executed**

Does someone can help me ?

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop "property does not exist on type JQuery" syntax errors when using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984014/how-can-i-stop-property-does-not-exist-on-type-jquery-syntax-errors-when-using)

Comment: nor interface or cast works for me. Code compile but plugin effect is not applied

Comment: Could it be a typo in your code? You declare `window["jQuery"] = $;` with lowercase `j` and the error message says `... does not exist on type 'JQuery'.` with capital `J`?

Comment: No change occured when i change case to correct with JQuery

Comment: Could you create an example application with [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: All the code is in the below document *updated*

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

in your base component only add to the imports section

```
declare var $:any;
```

and there after as per your ngOnit, you dont need $(document).ready() -> since it will be loaded on component intialization, like below

```
ngOnInit() {           
  this.http.get(
    this.configurationService.configuration['api_url']+"/generator/component/entitiesList").subscribe(
    data => {
      this.entities = data;
    }
  );      
  $('.loupe').okzoom({
      width: 200,
      height: 150
  });
}
```

In my case i just add the cdn links(jquery and other plugins) in index.html above body close tag and use above method and everything works fine, You can check with the import of plugins from script in angular.json as per your case.